# El curioso origen de la palabra "minga"

Tags: etimología, españa, sustantivos, vulgaridades

Entre las muchísimas palabras que se usan en nuestro idioma para referirse al miembro masculino, en el diccionario tenemos la siguiente:

> **[minga<sup>2</sup>](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PIgkP0D)**
>
> Acort. del n. p. *Dominga*.
>
> 1. f. malson. pene.

Debo decir que me llamó enormemente la atención de que la palabra se derivara de un nombre propio. Me fui a buscarlo al NTLLE y descubro que en el DLE solo lleva desde 1989, así que pensé que sería un término de reciente creación... hasta que me dio por mirar el diccionario del doctor Francisco del Rosal, de 1611, en el que se recoge:

> **Minga** al miembrecito de los niños, de Mingo, que en latín es orinar.

Vamos, que la palabra tiene de reciente lo que yo de cura. El diccionario de Terreros y Pando de 1787 insiste en que su etimología viene del latín *mingo, -is*, y lo define como "miembro natural del hombre". Por tanto, ¿por qué no se recogió en el DLE hasta 1989 si desde el siglo XVII ya se usaba? ¿Y a cuento de qué afirman que viene del acortamiento del nombre propio *Dominga*?

> *Suspirava Menga por la pinga axena. Komo el otro: "Llorava Ximena por la minga axena". "Pinga" dizen por lo ke los niños "minga".*
>
> Gonzalo Correas, "Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales", 1627 (España).

Comment: Interesante búsqueda e indagación. Siempre he pensado que "minga" viene de la misma palabra que "mingitorio" que viene del latin "minguere" que es orinar. No pensaba que pudiera venir de un nombre propio.

Comment: Sin querer ser Soez, la única referencia que conozco de minga, y dominga es esta:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q76ZvI5ejXk

Comment: En siciliano pene se dice minchia, así que origen latino es claro.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que la DRAE confundió dos sentidos de la palabra: un apodo infántil "Minga" que proviene de nombre Dominga, y la "minga" que trata del pene y del orinar (quizás onomatopoeticamente, quizás del *minguere* Latín -- gracias,  jalazbe).

Domingo y Dominga no tienen nada que ver con *minguere*, pero la DRAE los ha unido sin explicación en la definición [minga[2]](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PIgDkJ8%7CPIgkP0D).

Comment: En el texto de la pregunta se ve que en los siglos XVII y XVIII (antes de que se fundara la RAE) ya se usaba "minga" con el mismo significado que tiene hoy, y no con el sentido en latín de "orinar". ¿En qué te basas para afirmar que la RAE podría haber confundido los significados?

Comment: @Charlie no me sorprendió que una referencia al pene podría tener que ver con el orinar. Considera lo que es la _pinga_ y que en el portugués, _pingar_ es el nuestro _gotear_.

Comment: Volviendo al tema, me hace falta un lazo entre el miembro y los nombres Ximena y Dominga. Todos los sentidos son posibles, pero talvez no en una sola definición. ¿O notó Ud. conexión alguna?

Answer (score 1):

Por una parte, en cuanto a por qué no se recogió en el diccionario, seguramente tenga que ver con la costumbre de la RAE de no recoger palabras malsonantes en su diccionario hasta su edición de 1992, en la que se incorporaron multitud de voces malsonantes a las que hasta ahora se les había denegado el acceso a la obra.

Sobre su etimología, se le envió a la RAE una propuesta de cambio a la entrada de la palabra con las evidencias encontradas, y en la revisión de 2019 el artículo fue finalmente cambiado, luciendo ahora así:

> **[minga<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/minga)**
>
> Quizá derivado del latín *mingĕre* 'orinar'.
>
> 1. f. malson. pene.

Por tanto, la RAE ha considerado oportuno admitir (aunque con algunas reservas) el origen latino de la palabra.