# ¿Qué es una "minga" en Colombia?

Tags: significado, colombia

Mirando el periódico El Espectador de Colombia leí [este titular](https://colombia2020.elespectador.com/territorio/la-minga-indigena-le-responde-al-presidente-duque):

> **La *minga* indígena le responde al presidente Duque**
>
> La minga indígena y campesina del suroccidente colombiano sigue subiendo de tono (...)

La palabra *minga* me sorprendió, pues en España se entiende como palabra coloquial para *pene*, tal y como comentó Charlie en su día en [El curioso origen de la palabra "minga"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22569/1674).

Sin embargo, el tema del que habla esta noticia es serio y el uso de *minga* en nada tiene que ver con lo fálico.

El DLE describe:

> [**minga<sup>1</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PIgDkJ8%7CPIgkP0D)
>   `Del quechua mink'a.`
>
> 1. f. Arg., Chile, Col., Ec., Par. y Perú. Reunión de amigos y vecinos para hacer algún trabajo gratuito en común.
> 2. f. Ec. y Perú. Trabajo agrícola colectivo y gratuito con fines de utilidad social.

Pero el Diccionario de americanismos va más allá y explica:

> [**minga**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=XbGTbmILgx0AU6gya2d%7CgnyipRHr7x0AG2r9HaF%7C0Mk8Ujrdex0Aci9gORt%7CwgjEnzzR0x0Au9wKQPC)
>
> I. (Del quech. mink'a).
>   1.  f. Co, Ec, Py; Pe, Ch, Ar, rur. Reunión de amigos y vecinos que solidariamente realizan un trabajo en beneficio de alguno de ellos. (mingaco).
>   2.  Ec, Bo:SO; Pe, rur. Trabajo agrícola colectivo que se realiza gratuitamente y con fines sociales. (minca).
>   3.  Co. Institución social de solidaridad, vigente en los pueblos indígenas y campesinos.
>   4.  Ar:N, Ur. Fiesta o convite que el beneficiario de un trabajo común ofrece a quienes le han ayudado. rur.
>
> II.   1.  f. ES. Balón de futbol.

Y yo entiendo que la acepción de la que yo habla correspondería a la entrada I. 3:

> 3. Co. Institución social de solidaridad, vigente en los pueblos indígenas y campesinos.

¿Es así? ¿Qué es exactamente una *minga*?

Comment: A lo mejor esto podría ser útil: [minge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minge#Etymology_1). Este articulo presenta 3 posibles etimologías. También en este artículo podrá ver que en rumano `minge` tiene también el significado de `balón de futbol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hoy se realiza como minga cuadra similitud a la tercera acepción del DAMER...

En este caso, los pueblos indígenas están realizando una protesta por varios días y lo habitual es que no salga uno o dos pueblos, sino diferentes etnias a realizar estas protestas (ten en cuenta que se reconocen entre 87 y 102 pueblos indígenas actualmente).

En el sitio donde protestan, se juntan para colaborarse entre ellos para defensa y manutención (habitualmente se realizan las mingas de este tipo en carreteras, interrumpiendo el paso de vehículos). Igual se pueden organizar mingas en el primer sentido, de trabajar entre varias personas por un bien particular y quizá de ahí surge el tercer significado, de realizar un grupo 'temporal' de varios grupos para solicitar unas demandas a entidades públicas o privadas.

Comment: ¡interesante! Es decir que sería como una especie de sindicato